# adb cannot detect Xperia S

Tags: android, adb

I have an issue. 
I used Xperia S as Android device for testing my project. I followed the steps as below:
- connect the phone with laptop, turn on USB debugging
- I double checked in Device Manager, and laptop recognized my phone. (it means I can access the SDcard of the phone)
- in cmd promt, I typed "adb devices" => doesn't show any device connected, not even through Eclipse.
- I tried "adb usb" => show "error: device not found"
- I also tried to restart the adb server ("adb kill-server" and "adb start-server") but it still doesn't work. 
could anyone guide how can i connect my device to adb?

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: try reading a bit about [installing OEM drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 2):

you need to download and install sony xperia S driver for this to work.get it from here http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/support/phones/xperia-s/

Comment: thank you all, I solved my issues. Yea, just need to install the driver of my phone, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need ADB drivers installed to be able to do debugging. The fact your machine sees device as SD Card is irrelevant.